# Train/Test split object detection

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, object-detection, train-test-split

Are there any script/function to split the data counting the number of class appearances in each image and balance them?
I've tryed sklearn train_test_split in this way:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train_labels.csv')
data.head()
```

Class is what I want to predict, on one image I can have 0..n rectangles and each rectangle has a class.

[image]

```
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset="filename")
y = data['class']
X = data.drop('class',axis = 1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2)
```

But when I delete duplicates in filenames I'm loosing information and maybe I send files to train or test with many other classes, but if I don't delete them I can have a file in train and test.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might be looking for the `stratify` argument of [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). I think the call would be `train_test_split(X, y, test=0.2, stratify=y)`.

Comment: If you're looking to balance imbalanced classes, you can do that through different strategies like oversampling. Check out the docs on the [`imbalanced-learn`](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/over_sampling.html) Python package.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32818/train-test-split-of-unbalanced-dataset-classification

Answer (score 1):

Their is a library scikit-multilearn which will help to split multi-label data.

Installation: pip install scikit-multilearn

Documentation: http://scikit.ml/stratification.html

Implementation:

Let's suppose in dataframe `df`, `X1, X2` are the feature columns and `y` is the target column.

Our data can be classified in following classes *class1, class2, class3*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"X1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
"X2": [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],
"y": ["class1", "class1", "class2", "class2", "class3", "class3", "class1", "class2"]})
```

*After running above code we have dataframe:*

```
    X1  X2  y
0   1   6   class1
1   2   7   class1
2   3   8   class2
3   4   9   class2
4   5   10  class3
5   6   11  class3
6   7   12  class1
7   8   13  class2
```

But scikit multilearn works with one hot target columns. So we have to transform our target column.

```
one_hot_classes = pd.get_dummies(df["y"])
```

Which will output:

```
  class1 class2 class3
0   1      0      0
1   1      0      0
2   0      1      0
3   0      1      0
4   0      0      1
5   0      0      1
6   1      0      0
7   0      1      0
```

We will drop **y** column and concatenate `one_hot_classes`

```
df.drop("y", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df, one_hot_classes], axis=1)
```

*After running above code:*

```
    X1  X2   class1 class2 class3
0   1   6       1      0      0
1   2   7       1      0      0
2   3   8       0      1      0
3   4   9       0      1      0
4   5   10      0      0      1
5   6   11      0      0      1
6   7   12      1      0      0
7   8   13      0      1      0
```

Now we have features and target columns in X and y variable

```
X = df[["X1", "X2"]]
y = df[["class1", "class2", "class3"]]
```

Now we will get splits:

```
from skmultilearn.model_selection import iterative_train_test_split
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = iterative_train_test_split(X.values, y.values, test_size = 0.5)
```

Comment: I know this is old question but I stuck at how to applying this library for my work so I must ask this question. Can u provide ```X```, ```y``` format in ```iterative_train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.5)``` cause i coudn't find an answer from reading the author's documentation

Comment: @nOpe I have edited answer in more detailed implementation